# Any difference in using databricks table (delta) vs just reading a csv file for doing join?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a csv file that is used in 2 different Databricks notebooks for doing joins. Which approach is better in terms of performance and maintenance:

- Use a seperate notebook to create a Databricks delta table of the csv file and then refer to the databricks delta table in the 2 notebooks doing the join
- Just read in the csv file in each notebook and use it for the join.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the size of the csv file. If it is small (few MBs), it won't matter.
Large inputs are better stored in columnar formats like parquet or delta if you want good performance. They can be read faster due to compression and support pushdown of column projection (only reading needed columns) and some filters.
I suggest this talk if you are interested in optimizing your data for read performance with spark: https://databricks.com/session_eu19/the-parquet-format-and-performance-optimization-opportunities